# asynchronous webservice call

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

I am attempting to make an asynchronous web service call for speed via Java API. I wish to send a payload of over 1000 users and their corresponding attributes. My question is, would making the call multi threaded so that each thread sends a single insert user request be faster than sending all users in one payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your webservice is organized, mainly, whether it is itself  multithreaded.

If it is, sending several simultaneous requests make sense, but chances are optimal number of simultaneous requests is less than 1000. I would start with 10 requests with 100 users each, and then change that parameters to find optimal number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since each thread uses the same network port, I would not assume the multi-threading will speed up the sending - on the contrary, I think the overhead of negotiating the usage .